# Linux search and replace a patterns case within a string

Tags: regex, awk, sed

Been struggling to figure out a way to do this. Basically I need to change the case of **anything** enclosed in {} from lower to upper within a string representing a uri (and also strip out the braces but I can use sed to do that)

E.g

```
/logs/{server_id}/path/{os_id}
```

To

```
/logs/SERVER_ID/path/OS_ID
```

The case of the rest of the string must be preserved in lower which is what has been beating me. Looked at combos of sed,awk,tr with regex so far. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Should `{SERVER{ONE}_ID}` be replaced for `SERVERONE_ID` or do inner braces remain untouched? (i.e `SERVER{ONE}_ID` )

Comment: Hi Alejandro, inner braces should get stripped out too. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 sed "s/{\([^{}]*\)}/\U\1/g"
```

This works by matching all text enclosed within `{}` and replacing it with its uppercase version.

```
echo "/logs/{server_id}/path/{os_id}" | sed "s/{\([^{}]*\)}/\U\1/g"
```

Gives `/logs/SERVER_ID/path/OS_ID` as the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "/logs/{server_id}/path/{os_id}" \
| sed 's#{\([^{}][^{}]*\)}#\U\1#;s#{\([^{}][^{}]*\)}#\U\1#'
```

**output**

```
/logs/SERVER_ID/path/OS_ID
```

The part of the solution you seem to have missed is the 'capture groups' available in sed, i.e. `\(regex\)`. This is then referenced by `\1`. You could have anywhere from `1-9` capture groups if you're a real masochist ;-)

Also note that I just repeat the same cmd 2 times, as the first `{...}` pair as been converted to the UC version (without surrounding `{}`s), so only remaining `{...}` targets will match.

There are probably less verbose syntax available for `[^{}][^{}*` but this will work with just about any `sed` going back to the 80s. I seem to recall that some `sed`s don't support the `\U` directive, but for the systems I have access to, this works.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{
      while(match($0,/{[^}]+}/)) 
          $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) toupper(substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}1' file
/logs/SERVER_ID/path/OS_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This one handles arbitrary number and format of braces:

```
echo "/logs/{server_id}/path/{os_id}/{foo}" | awk -v RS='{' -v FS='}' -v ORS='\0' -v OFS='\0' '!/}/ { print } /}/ { $1 = toupper($1); print}'
```

Output:

```
 /logs/SERVER_ID/path/OS_ID/FOO
```